# how to display all the rowspan datas while search

Tags: javascript, html

when seaching first data in table it didn't display the span value. and also the table  alignment also changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

});

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <th>header2</th>
    <th>header3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Anja</td>
   <td>Ravendale</td>
   <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

when i search john want to show all the three datas Moe, Doe, Dooley

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is first loop through the rows that have cells with `rowspan` and take that text and add it to all the rows involved using `data()`

Then in `filter()` check both row `data()` and `text()`

Something like:

```js
$(function() {

  var $rows = $('#myTable tr');

  $rows.filter(':has(td[rowspan])').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this),
      rowIdx = $row.index(),
      $spanCell = $row.find('[rowspan]'),
      txt = $spanCell.text().trim().toLowerCase(),
      rowspan = +$spanCell.attr('rowspan');

    $rows.slice(rowIdx, rowIdx + rowspan).data('spanTxt', txt);
  });


  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // show all when no value
    if(!value){
       $rows.show();
       return
    }    
    
    // hide all , then filter ones to show
    $rows.hide().filter(function() {
      var $row = $(this),
        txt = $row.text().toLowerCase(),
        spanTxt = $row.data('spanTxt') || '';            
       
      // true if either data or row text includes search term
      return txt.includes(value) || spanTxt.includes(value)
    }).show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For multiple `rowspan` in a row you may need to make the data an array rather than string

Comment: it works perfectly. thanks. when i search Moe again it display without showing john.. what should i do for this now? @charlietfl

Comment: I expected bugs but that one is wierd because `doe` works fine

Comment: Ahh... I think it can't show John when row with the rowspan cell is hidden. Will play with it some more. Think it is more complicated than my iniital attempt that worked with some of them. probably have to hide cells instead of rows when rowspan is involved

Comment: Too late for me to do much more tonight though